# Antigoogleying system

Tags: java

I need to design a testing system which would not allow to use google. I mean that, theoretically, the user still can do it, but the purpose is to hinder this as much as possible. 
I have an idea, but I don't know how good it is. I want the question in the database to be a simple text. And when we need to load it to the test, we convert it into a picture with a watermark. But the problem is that, theoretically, it still can be recognized. Google is able to convert the text on the image into the text and then search it as a text. Google is also able to recognize images despite some hue differences on them. Does anybody have proposals on that score? What would you do?

Comment: if you dont allow user to do Context click (Right mouse Click) user cannot easily copy the text .

Comment: not sure what exactly your requirements are but there are many commercial application which can block / filter traffic to particular websites such as [this](http://www.websense.com/content/home.aspx)

Comment: "if you dont allow user to do Context click (Right mouse Click) user cannot easily copy the text", but the user can still easily switch off the css. And the problem that the users I have know how to do so.

Comment: Ok. To be more clear. I have a question on the screen. The question is not necessarily rare or unique and other resources can contain it. So I can just cut it, save on my computer and insert into google search by picture. The goal is to make something which is still comfortable to read, but doesn't allow google to recognize it. I need a very readable captcha. But it looks like I want too much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use [robots exclusion](http://googleblog.blogspot.co.nz/2007/02/robots-exclusion-protocol.html) headers on the page to tell google not to store your page.   or even robots.txt

As you say if it's human-readable, google will read it.  Google has millions of slaves doing OCR for them (via Re-Captcha).  but if you tell google to leave your site alone, it will.